# Redirect to the original URL after signin using Spring Social, Spring security?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security, spring-social

Spring social and security experts,

I have the following use case:

1. User requests a specific URL like http://www.foobar.com/foo/1001
2. Anonymous user can see this page but cannot post a comment in this page. Comment posting part is secured by Spring security.
3. User clicks login. It pops up a login window or redirect it to login page.
4. The user chooses to sign in with Facebook ID.
5. After user signed in using FB, it redirects the user to http://www.foobar.com/foo/1001 with authorization.

I was wondering how I can do that using Spring Social. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'm not sure with Spring Social, but you would have to store the last request made in the `HttpSession`. When logic is finished you would send a redirect with the path of the previous request.

Comment: This is an approach I would try if I am not using Spring Security and Spring Social. Spring security is doing redirect automatically. For Spring Social, there's a signin controller, but I don't know how it works. I guess it only supports one level redirect, which means redirecting to login page after you successfully login with your social account.

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tried it to see if it works? Spring security does this automatically.

If you are an anonymous user and attempt to access a resource that requires a certain permission, spring security will store the attempted URL and redirect you to the login page. After successful login it fetches the attempted URL back and redirects you there.

Comment: Yes. I have tried that. Spring security does a good job on redirecting to the page I requested. However, I am using spring social. The flow is you tried to access a URL that is secured, spring security prompts you to login and redirects you to the login page. Then you choose to signin with Facebook. The Spring Social will direct you to FB to complete login. If it is successful, it will redirect you back to the login page, which is the original URL you left, but not the URL you requested before login page.

Answer (score 0):

I have only managed to do this by copy/pasting code which spring security uses to do this job.

CAVEAT: I am using [ProviderSignInController](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-social/current/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/social/connect/web/ProviderSignInController.html) to provision accounts and sign in.

ProviderSignInController permits the use of a [SignInAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-social/current/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/social/connect/web/ProviderSignInController.html) to manually login local user account based on the SocialConnection

In the signIn method:

```
public String signIn(String userId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest request)
```

I have the following code:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request.getNativeRequest();
HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse)request.getNativeResponse();

RequestCache rc = new HttpSessionRequestCache();
SavedRequest savedRequest = rc.getRequest(req, resp);
String targetUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
if(targetUrl != null){
     log.info("Redirecting to DefaultSavedRequest Url: " + targetUrl);
     new DefaultRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(req, resp, targetUrl);
     hasSentRedirect = true;
}
```

I had to dig through the code of [SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) to see how this works as part of spring security.

I am disappointed that ProviderSignInController isn't really linked to Spring Security at all. And so we must hack our way around to get the same functionality.
I have also found that login events aren't posted either.

I have asked about this recently: [Should I use both SocialAuthenticationFilter and ProviderSignInController together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802112/should-i-use-both-socialauthenticationfilter-and-providersignincontroller-togeth)