# How to redirect dynamic url using spring social framework after successful log in?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-social

I have written code for fb,g+,twitter. After succuessful login. this method will work Everytime user logs in. it gets different id from my code. is it possible to change url dynamically at runtime in spring security config. please help me with it.

example code for Twitter:

```
<form id="tw_signin" action="<c:url value="/signin/twitter"/>" method="POST">
  <button type="submit">
    <img src="<c:url value="/resources/social/twitter/sign-in-with-twitter-d.png"/>" />
  </button>
</form>
```

securityconfig.java

```
public SpringSocialConfigurer getSpringSocialConfigurer() {
        SpringSocialConfigurer config = new SpringSocialConfigurer();
        config.alwaysUsePostLoginUrl(true);
        if(true) {
             config.postLoginUrl("/event?eventid="+id);
        } 
        return config;
    }
```

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/39897395/180100

Comment: event id continuously changes. what should i do with this id?